# slicing rows from csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read a csv file in python and build a data frame from it. 
Here is an example of a row from my csv file:

|ab/5 (cd ef 6| text1/123 (lala| ghj) lal/1234/567|

I would like to slice the row and assign each element to a column.
The row should look sit in the data frame like so:

```
col1 |  col2                     | col3
ab/5 | (cd ef 6| text1/123 (lala | ghj)
```

Setting up a distributor while opening the file in excel is pointless because sometimes '|' appears in place, in which case it should not be split.
For the first element ab/5 I was trying to do it like this:

```
with open('actions2.csv', 'r') as csvfile_actions2:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile_actions2)
    for row in reader:
        row2=row[0:23].split('|')
        print(row2)
```

However, an error occurred:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: you need to convert to string first. so str(row[0:23]).split(|)

Comment: Unfortunately, this could be only done with regex expressions, beacuse | and || are in differnt places in various rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to use the `csv.reader` function if you intend to delimitate manually. You can instead use `open` and split the line at the first instance of '|' as shown below:

```
with open('actions2.csv', 'r') as csvfile_actions2:
    for row in csvfile_actions2:
        row2 = row[0:23].split('|',1)
        print(row2)
```

The `split('|',1)` function will split the string only at the first '|' character. If you wish to remove the whitespace, you can also add `.replace(' ','')` before `split`.

Alternatively, if your csv file is only 3 columns and the extra '|' characters only appear in column 2 as shown in your example, then you can recombine them after using `csv.reader`

```
with open('actions2.csv', 'r') as csvfile_actions2:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile_actions2, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) == 4:
            row = [row[0], row[1] + '|' + row[2], row[3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong way to implement split.

You should do "cell" parsing while you're reading csv, not after. For python `csv` module, dialects support [custom delimiters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter). So, you can just do

```
with open('actions2.csv', 'r') as csvfile_actions2:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile_actions2, delimiter='|')
```

`csv.reader` will do all parsing and splitting for you, and you will iterate over parsed lists

Look for more [examples and recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) in docs

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
with open('actions2.csv') as f:
    content = f.read()
    comp_list = content.split("\n")[0:23]
    for i in comp_list:
        new_list = i.split("|")
        print (new_list)
```